# Trying to store array from main to an array in another function

Tags: python, arrays

This program should create an array in main and prompts the user to enter 5 integers and store them in the array in a function called fibArray. It then creates a function named containOnlyOdd that excepts the array and returns a true if the array contains only odd numbers or false if it does not. print a message indicating the results such as ex: [1,2,3,4,5] "The array contains both odd and even numbers." or [1,3,5,7,9] "The array contains only odd numbers.

The error is get is in line 10 in fibArray which is fibArray = [0] * num. TypeError: Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type list.

```
def main():
    integer = 5
    intArray = [0] * integer
    for index in range(integer):
        intArray[index] = int(input("Enter integers:"))
    print(intArray)
    fibArray(intArray)

def fibArray(num):
    fibArray = [0] * num
    for index in range(num):
        print(num)

def containsOnlyOdds(lst):
    for num in lst:
    if num % 2 == 0
        #print("This list is all odd")
         return false`
    #print("This list has even numbers")            
    return True

main()
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!!

Comment: please please please rephrase the title. "I tried that"?... you tried what?

Comment: You're passing a list where it looks like your expecting an int.

Comment: @ shx2 I changed the title :). @ valeHalfHeart any suggestions or help would be great. I am a beginner!! What should it look like?

Comment: In addition to the problems you are having with the main error message, you will need to properly indent you "if" statement in the function containsOnlyOdds.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly, what the error message states: you hand an array to fibArray:

```
fibArray(intArray)
```

which in turn tries to multiply it with *[0]*:

```
fibArray = [0] * num
```

You may only call fibArray and pass a number, but not an array.

**edit/add:**

The numbers are already stored in the array intArray. No need for the function fibArray. Of course you could alternatively pass the numbers to a function which then again stores the values. Since you are just beginning python, i recommend leaving it with the value-checking-function for now. Once the program works, you can try to encapsulate part of the code in another function.

There is also some syntax errors in the definition of *def containsOnlyOdds(lst)*: You should fix the indentation of the loop and if-statement. Also, you are missing a colon after the statement, e.g.

```
for anElement in aList:
    if (statement):
        #do something, e.g. return False
    #do something else, e.g. return True
```

Comment: Any suggestions on changes I should apply to make it work. I am greatful for any help. I am a beginner at all this.

Comment: I added the variable num = 5 in the fibArray function and the code works, but after I run it prints 5 5's not the print statement. So i can print from my last function.

Comment: Of course it will print 5 5s.. you have a statement that says: *for index in range(num):
        print(num)*.. Like I suggested earlier, please check on the definition and usage of loops and come back once you have a new question.